# Why is my ngrx action causing an endless loop?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have one simple action in which I want to add some object into an array in my state. Somehow it runs into an endless loop. I couldn't figure out yet why it is happening. I am new to ngrx and Angular. What am I doing wrong? The action is fired after clicking on the button, which is calling following function`onAddToCartButtonClicked()` in `shelf-item.component.ts`

This is my reducer in `reducer.ts`:

```
export type ShoppinCartState = {
  CartIsOpen: boolean;
  Entries: ShoppingCartEntry[];
};


export function shoppingCartReducer(
  state: ShoppinCartState = { CartIsOpen: false, Entries: [] },
  action: ShoppingCartAction
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CART_TOGGLE":
      return {
        ...state,
        CartIsOpen: !state.CartIsOpen
      };
    case "CART_CLOSE":
      return {
        ...state,
        CartIsOpen: false
      };
    case "CART_ADD_ENTRY":
      return {
        ...state,
        Entries: [...state.Entries.concat(action.payload)]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This is basically my `shelf-item-component.ts`

```
export class ShelfItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() product: Product;
  selectedOption: ProductVariant;
  isInputMissing: boolean = false;

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.product && this.product.variations) {
      if (this.product.variations.length === 1) {
        this.selectedOption = this.product.variations[0];
      }
    }
  }

  onAddToCartButtonClicked() {
    if (this.isValid()) {
      this.addProductToCart();
    }
  }

  addProductToCart() {
    this.store.dispatch({ type: "SET_LOADING" });
    this.store
      .select(state => state.shoppingCartReducer.Entries)
      .subscribe(data => this.dispatchNewCartEntry(data));
  }

  dispatchNewCartEntry(entries: ShoppingCartEntry[]) {
    this.store.dispatch(
      new AddShoppingCartEntry(this.constructNewCartEntry(entries))
    );
    this.store.dispatch({ type: "UNSET_LOADING" });
  }

  constructNewCartEntry(entries: ShoppingCartEntry[]): ShoppingCartEntry {
    let matchingEntry = entries.find(
      entry =>
        entry.product.id === this.product.id &&
        entry.variation === this.selectedOption
    );
    let amount = matchingEntry ? matchingEntry.amount + 1 : 1;
    return {
      product: this.product,
      amount: amount,
      variation: this.selectedOption
    };
  }

  isValid(): boolean {
    if (this.isOptionToBeSelected()) {
      if (this.selectedOption) {
        this.isInputMissing = false;
        return true;
      } else {
        this.isInputMissing = true;
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  isOptionToBeSelected(): boolean {
    if (this.product && this.product.variations.length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  onOptionSelected(option: ProductVariant) {
    this.selectedOption = option;
    this.isInputMissing = false;
  }
}
```

Thats my `shelf-item-component.html`

```
<h3>{{ product.title }}</h3>
<img *ngIf="!product.image" src="../../../assets/img/esansBottles Kopie.png" />
<div
  [ngClass]="{ inValid: isInputMissing }"
  *ngIf="product.variations.length > 1"
>
  <form>
    <div class="variation" *ngFor="let variation of product.variations">
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="variation"
          value="variation"
          (change)="onOptionSelected(variation)"
        />
        {{ variation.option }} {{ variation.price }} €</label
      >
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div *ngIf="product.variations.length === 1">
  <div *ngIf="selectedOption">
    {{ selectedOption.option }} {{ selectedOption.price }}€
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
</div>
<div (click)="onAddToCartButtonClicked()" class="addToCartButton">
  In den Warenkorb
</div>
```

And this is the parent component shelf.component.html in which the problematic component is created:

```
<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let product of products | async">
    <app-shelf-item [product]="product"></app-shelf-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

And it's `shelf.component.ts file`:

```
export class ShelfComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() products: Observable<Product[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

I am really stuck and don't understand it :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Fateh mentioned, it will be triggered and the values will be subscribed. If this action is to be fired once upon subscribing to the store selector, you may chain the above statement the RxJS [take()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/take.html) operator.

This operator will ensure that only the specified count values supplied to be take() operator will be emitted by the source observable.

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.store
  .pipe(
    select(state => state.shoppingCartReducer.Entries}),
    take(1),
  ).subscribe(data => {
    this.dispatchNewCartEntry(data);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Pipe and take(1) seem to be interesting. It didn't work at the first try. I think I have to install RxJS to use it. I simply extracted the list subscribe call to the constructor and save it to a local variable, which I use later in the onClick Handler. Seems to be working as well...

Comment: You are using Angular, aren't you? RxJS is installed by default. You only need to import the take operator to your component! `import { take } from 'rxjs/operators;'. You will need to add this somewhere along the top of your file 
`

Comment: Ah okay ... didn't know that... I will try out again later

Comment: ` this.store
      .pipe(
        select(state => state.shoppingCartReducer.Entries),
        take(1)
      )
      .subscribe(data => this.dispatchNewCartEntry(data));`

Comment: awesome! Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem - completely my fault - the reducer and effects were in an infinite cycle. Spent hours debugging, only to find out that I had duplicated the action names in a copy-paste-cident (sickening >.<)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's normal, You are subscribing to shopping cart entities here

```
this.store
  .select(state => state.shoppingCartReducer.Entries)
  .subscribe(data => this.dispatchNewCartEntry(data));
```

that means that each times shoppingcart entries change , dispatch will be triggered inside the subscription

Comment: Thank you Fateh. Don't know how I couldn't see that.